# Node.js: Response empty when i want to edit a provider

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a CRUD app with create, get, update and delete providers.

Create and get are working perfectly, but I have problems with the update function. When I want to get the response it is empty. I don't know why if in  `app.post("/proveedor/new"),function(req,res){console.log(req.body)});` are printing the body and in `app.put("/proveedor/:id")....` they are not giving me data.

```
extends ../layout.jade
block contenido
div(class="col-md-3 center-block no-float top-space")
    h1 Editar Proveedor
    form(method="POST" action="/proveedor/#{product.id}?_method=put" style="margin-top:1.5em;" enctype="multipart/form-data")   

        div(class="form-group")
            label Nombre
            input(type="text" value="#{product.title}" name="titulo" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" class="form-control")
        div(class="form-group")
            label Descripcion
            input(type="text" value="#{product.description}" name="descripcion" placeholder="Ingresa tu descripcion" class="form-control")
        div(class="form-group")
            label Costo
            input(type="nombre" value="#{product.pricing}" name="costo" placeholder="Ingresa costo" class="form-control")
        div(class="form-group")
            input(type="file" name="avatar")
        div(class="form-group")
            label Contrasena
            input(type="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contrasena" class="form-control")     
        div(class="form-group text-right")              
            input(type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Guardar")
```

And my app.js

```
            var express = require('express');
            var mongoose = require('mongoose');
            var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
            var multer  = require('multer');
            var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});
            var fs = require('fs');
            var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
            var method_override = require("method-override");
            var app_password = "12345";

            var app = express();

app.put("/proveedor/:id",function(solicitud,respuesta){
console.log(solicitud.body);
if(solicitud.body.password == app_password){
    var data = {
        title: solicitud.body.title,
        description: solicitud.body.description,
        pricing: solicitud.body.pricing
    };

    if(solicitud.files.hasOwnProperty("avatar")){
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(solicitud.files.image_avatar.path, 
            function(result) {
                data.imageUrl = result.url;

                Product.update({"_id": solicitud.params.id},data,function(product){
                    respuesta.redirect("/menu");
                });
            }
        );          
    }else{
        Product.update({"_id": solicitud.params.id},data,function(product){
            respuesta.redirect("/menu");
        });
    }   


    }else{
        respuesta.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new to nodejs. I think the problem may be the multipart/form-data post. Even you use body-parser, you still can't get data from your multipart post directly.

[body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser): This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature.

Thus, when you validate the password, it would not pass forever, because your password would be undefined or nothing.
You would need [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) to analyze your multipart post.

However, I am confused you said you can print something in your create function. I think it would print undefined, but it didn't.

Comment: Yes yesterday a figure out that. Multer was the solution. Thanks buddy.